# Cannot drop shadow on bitmap with SetShadowLayer

Tags: android, bitmap

I am trying to add a shadow to my bitmap image, but I cannot figure out why it is not happening:

```
    public static Bitmap pimpMyBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) { // Scales down, adds rounded edges and shadow

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(360, 240, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff424242;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, 360, 240);
    final float roundPx = 12;

    paint.setShadowLayer(5.5f, 6.0f, 6.0f, 0xFF000000); 

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rectF, paint);

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using honeycomb and above, make sure to use software layers because as of version 4.2 setShadowLayer is not supported by the accelerated canvas pipeline for anything other than text.

So right before your canvas.drawBitmap do something like this:

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

For more info read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html (scroll down to "Unsupported Drawing Operations" section)